# Create GIF from Video

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, gif

I have a code that get a video URL from the photo library

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

}
```

How can I create a exportable GIF from that in Objective-C?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Yes you can.](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift)

*The better question is why?* GIFs are notoriously large in file size and low in quality. In fact, many of the 'GIFs' you see online or within other apps aren't actually GIFs but instead silent mp4 files (either created from a GIF or originally designed to look like a GIF).

Twitter, and many other top sites use this strategy as the file sizes are typically <10% compared to a similar GIF with the mp4's quality far outperforming the GIF's. I'd recommend you take this approach unless you specifically need a GIF file.